# Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to look it up later

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
  

    //13---getting data from our arrays

    holder.book_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_id.get(position)));
    holder.book_title_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_title.get(position)));
    holder.book_author_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_author.get(position)));
    holder.book_pages_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_pages.get(position)));

    holder.mainLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
            // transferring data inside activity
            intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(book_id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf(book_title.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("author", String.valueOf(book_author.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("pages", String.valueOf(book_pages.get(position)));


            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}
```

Currently I've got recommendation as for using holder.getAdapterPosition, but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: More precise - its int position highlighted by red

Comment: Viewholders position might change between binding and click, that's why you should not capture `position` argument. At the top of your `onClick` add `int position = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();` to obtain current position.

Comment: Seems good so far) Thanx a lot